# symfony1 multiple checkboxes require all

Tags: checkbox, symfony1

I want to require all checkboxes in the set

My code looks like this:

```
     $this->widgetSchema['consent_confirmation'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox(
        array(
          'choices' => Doctrine_Core::getTable('MyTable')->getOptions(),
        )
    );
```

UPDATE:

My validation looks like this:

```
$this->validatorSchema['consent_confirmation'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
    'choices' => array(Doctrine_Core::getTable('MyTable')->getOptions()),
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => true
));
```

How can I make it return 'Required' if they're not all checked, and be valid if they're all checked?

Comment: Have you added any rules to the `validationSchema` for the checkbox? if you do can you post it?

Comment: See update in post for validationSchema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My symfony 1.* memory is very hazy at this point but I think what you need to do here is add a rule to the `validatorSchema` to handle validation of this widget.

According to the [Validation Appendix](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators) the validator you need is [`sfValidatorChoice`](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatorchoice).

This widget has a number of options, including:

- multiple
- min
- max

Assuming that you have two options as above, and you want to enforce selecting both, I'm guessing that you might need to add the following to your form's `configure()` method:

```
public function configure()
{
    $this->widgetSchema['consent_confirmation'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox(array(
        'choices' => array(
            '1' => 'Yes I agree to #1',
            '2' => 'Yes I agree to #2',             
        )),
    );

    $this->validatorSchema['consent_confirmation'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'min'      => 2,
        'max'      => 2,
    ));
}
```

Something like that - I'm not sure about the assignment to the validatorSchema to be honest, there might be something like `addValidator()` or `setValidator()`methods instead. EDIT: I think there were some helper methods added, but some of these might be 1.4 specific. The above assignment should work either way...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please see my update. I tried adding that, but it gives me 'Invalid' if more than one is checked, even if they're all checked.

Comment: Hmm... it's hard to advise on this from memory alone. Invalid is very cryptic isn't it? Does the same error occur if you remove `choices` from the validator?

Comment: ah! great :) glad to hear it!